# How to segment/weigh cost and training data differently based on importance, for neural networks

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, time-series

I'm looking for ideas/direction to address a problem I have:

**Context:** I have hourly time-series data (i.e. one row of features for each of the 24 hours in a day), for 1000s of days. For each hour, I'm trying to predict a target value. Now, **I care more about the accuracy of certain hours of the day** (e.g. 08:00-18:00) vs. the remaining hours of the day.

**Problem/Question:** how can I adjust my cost function to be more concerned with the accuracy in these key hours? Or is it a matter of weighing the data set differently, to give more weight to hours 08:00-18:00?

**Approach:** I've coded up a MLP in Tensorflow and am using mean square error as my cost function, and Adam as the optimizer. And while this approach is good for increasing overall accuracy (i.e. >90%), the accuracy in our key hours is not high enough.

Here's my cost function:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(pred-y)/y)
```

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a placeholder (batch size by 1) that represents how important a particular training example is. Get cost for each row in your batch (batch size by 1), and pointwise multiply your placeholder by your cost.

Comment: Great idea & thanks for your reply. That's what I was thinking too- multiplying the cost by a vector of constants that differ based on how important an hour is. So each hour's cost has a corresponding multiplier.

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of, but this would be difficult to tune for 24 hours. I wonder if you can learn the weights somehow? Maybe some type of attention mechanism? Isn't that what those are for?

Comment: oh good point re: attention! I will look into that. And yeah, I'm going to change the shape of my inputs so I feed it in as 24-hr blocks at a time.